# Clicking on a mounted drive on the launcher doesn't open it

Tags: unity, 11.10, launcher

My external drive is mounted as /media/usr2 and is visible in the "dock". When I right-click it, "Open" is one of the options but it never opens. Why does "Open" not work?

Answer (score 1):

Just click the icon in the launcher, don't right-click it. `nautilus`, the default filebrowser in 11.10, should open.

Answer (score 0):

In Nautilus -- the file browser you use to display you home folder -- you select Filesystem from the list on the left hand side. That will show you the contents of /, including /media. Just click it and then click usr2 and you'll see everything. :)